# Alamofire 5 multiple token refresh issue in AuthenticationInterceptor

Tags: swift, jwt, token, alamofire, refresh-token

After changing public and private keys for jwt token (on the server), Alamofire interceptor for authorization is triggering token refresh multiple times and after that calls next API Call without putting authorization header with token and displaying an error.

```
Alamofire.AFError.requestAdaptationFailed(error: Alamofire.AuthenticationError.excessiveRefresh)
```

Response from the token refresh is fine and it's getting the token but for some reason it's refreshing the token again.

On WEB, Android (Retrofit) and Postman everything is fine and working as it should be.

Im using Alamofire 5.4.3 and Swift

Did someone have the same problem and how to solve it or get what is root cause?

Here is the Interceptor

```
let interceptor: Interceptor
let interceptors: [RequestInterceptor]
        if let token = token {
            let authenticator = OAuthAuthenticator(host: host, onRefreshFail: onRefreshFail)
            interceptors =  [AuthenticationInterceptor<OAuthAuthenticator>(authenticator: authenticator, credential: OAuthCredential(token: token))]
        } else {
            interceptors = []
        }
        self.interceptor = Interceptor(adapters: [PlatformAdapter()], interceptors: interceptors)
```

AuthenticationCredential

```
struct OAuthCredential: AuthenticationCredential {
let accessToken: String
let refreshToken: String
let expiry: Date
let twoFactorMethod: String?

var requiresRefresh: Bool {
    return Date().addingTimeInterval(5 * 60) > expiry
}

init(token: AuthorizationToken) {
    self.accessToken = token.token
    self.refreshToken = token.refreshToken!
    self.twoFactorMethod = token.twoFactorMethod
    if let jwt = try? decode(jwt: token.token), let expiryDate = jwt.expiresAt {
        self.expiry = expiryDate
    } else {
        self.expiry = Date()
    }
}
```

}

Authenticator

```
class OAuthAuthenticator: Authenticator {
typealias Credential = OAuthCredential
let host: String
let onRefreshFail: () -> ()

init(host: String, onRefreshFail: @escaping () -> ()) {
    self.host = host
    self.onRefreshFail = onRefreshFail
}

func apply(_ credential: OAuthCredential, to urlRequest: inout URLRequest) {
    urlRequest.headers.add(.authorization(bearerToken: credential.accessToken))
}

func refresh(_ credential: OAuthCredential, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<OAuthCredential, Error>) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://\(host)/api/v1/token-refresh")!)
    request.method = .post
    request.headers.add(.init(name: "X-Client", value: "iOS"))
    request.headers.add(.contentType("application/json"))
    request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(["refreshToken": credential.refreshToken])
    AF.request(request).responseDecodable(of: AuthorizationToken.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()) { [weak self] response in
        debugPrint(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let token):
            completion(.success(OAuthCredential(token: token)))
        case .failure(let error):
            self?.onRefreshFail()
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }.cURLDescription { curl in
        print(curl)
    }
}

func didRequest(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, with response: HTTPURLResponse, failDueToAuthenticationError error: Error) -> Bool {
    return response.statusCode == 401
}

func isRequest(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, authenticatedWith credential: OAuthCredential) -> Bool {
    let bearerToken = HTTPHeader.authorization(bearerToken: credential.accessToken).value
    return urlRequest.headers["Authorization"] == bearerToken
}
```

}

RequestAdapter

```
private class PlatformAdapter: RequestAdapter {
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
    var request = urlRequest
    request.headers.add(.init(name: "X-Client", value: "iOS"))
    completion(.success(request))
}
```

}

This is the debugprint for token refresh

```
[Request]: POST https://***masked.host***/api/v1/token-refresh
[Headers]:
    Content-Type: application/json
    X-Client: iOS
[Body]:
    {"refreshToken":"d8803e9fc4c9e5..."}
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 200
    [Headers]:
        access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Client, X-Client-Timezone, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, JSNLog-RequestId, activityId, applicationId, applicationUserId, channelId, senderId, sessionId
        access-control-allow-methods: GET, DELETE, OPTIONS, POST, PUT
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
        access-control-max-age: 3628800
        Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate
        Content-Type: application/json
        Date: Wed, 07 Jun 2023 12:53:24 GMT
        Expires: 0
        Pragma: no-cache
        Server: nginx-n.wtf/1.23.2
        Transfer-Encoding: Identity
        x-frame-options: DENY
        x-powered-by: PHP/8.1.13
    [Body]:
        {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC...","refreshExpireAt":1696510404}
[Network Duration]: 0.24588894844055176s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0001188850001199171s
[Result]: success(AuthorizationToken(token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI...", refreshToken: Optional("6535d9c6bf29a458b945b456..."), twoFactorMethod: nil, username: nil, requirements: nil))
```

This is curl from API call that should contain authorization header

```
$ curl -v \
-X GET \
-H "User-Agent: ***masked***/1.4.24 (com.***masked***; build:99; iOS 16.4.0) Alamofire/5.4.3" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.9, deflate;q=0.8" \
-H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://***masked.host***/api/v1/employee/163/global-state"
```